# Google Charts Diff Chart with custom toolip

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I have to draw diff pie chart and show custom tooltip text instead of default Old and Current values. Here is the code I use. What should I change to show "my tooltip" and "my another tooltip" instead of default tootip texts?

```
var d = new google.visualization.DataTable({"cols": [
{"type": "string" ,"id": "Title"   ,"label": "Title" }, 
{"type": "number" ,"id": "Count" ,"label": "Count", "p": {"role" : "old-data"} },
{"type": "number" ,"id": "Count" ,"label": "Count", "p": {"role" : "data"} }, 
{"type": "string" ,"id": "Tooltip" ,"label": "Tooltip" , "p": {"role" : "tooltip"}}], 
"rows" : [
{"c" : [{"v": "Item1"}, {"v": 0}, {"v": 28}, {"v": "my tooltip"}]}, 
{"c" : [{"v": "Item2"}, {"v": 80}, {"v": 0}, {"v": "my another tooltip"}]}]});

var options = { pieSliceText: 'none', diff: { innerCircle: { radiusFactor: 0.3 } },    sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0, pieSliceText: 'label'};

var chartDiff = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_diff'));
chartDiff.draw(d, options);
```

Comment: PieCharts don't support the "tooltip" column role for changing tooltip text.  Your only option is to format the data for display.

Comment: There's a bug report about this issue: https://code.google.com/p/google-visualization-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1455

Answer (score 2):

Was stuck with this problem since long time. Finally got a hack to fix it.
Her is my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

  function drawChart() {

    var oldData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Status', 'Percentage'],
      ['Error', 60], ['Success', 40]]);

    var newData = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['Status', 'Percentage'],
      ['Error', 80], ['Success', 20]]);

    var options = {
     tooltip: { isHtml: true }
   }
    var chartDiff = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart_diff'));

    var diffData = chartDiff.computeDiff(oldData, newData);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chartDiff,'onmouseover',selectHandler);

    function selectHandler(){
      console.log("Entered");
      $('#piechart_diff').on("DOMNodeInserted",function(e){
       //console.log(e.target);
        if($(e.target).is('.google-visualization-tooltip')){
         console.log(document.getElementsByClassName('google-visualization-tooltip-item')[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML);
         document.getElementsByClassName('google-visualization-tooltip-item')[1].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = 'Test1 :';
         document.getElementsByClassName('google-visualization-tooltip-item')[2].getElementsByTagName('span')[0].innerHTML = "Test2 :";
          //console.log(e);
          //e.target.innerHTML = "<p>test1 error :"+te1+"%<br />test2 error :"+te2+"%</p>";
        }
      })
    }

    chartDiff.draw(diffData, options);
  }
</script>
```

```html
<span id='piechart_diff' style='width: 450px; position: absolute; left: 250px'></span>
```

Main trick is adding tooltip: {isHtml :true} and then traversing till we find the tooltip

Answer (score 2):

If your tooltip doesn't change per row then you can utilize chart options (applying to your options):

```
var options = {
  pieSliceText: 'none',
  diff: {
    innerCircle: {
      radiusFactor: 0.3
    },
    oldData: {
      tooltip: {
        prefix: 'my tooltip'
      }
    },
    newData: {
      tooltip: {
        prefix: 'my another tooltip'
      }
    }
  },
  sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0,
  pieSliceText: 'label'
```

};

Having per row tooltip or annotation customization does not seem to possible at the moment without ugly DOM manipulation hacks.

Working demo & source (easily changeable to PieChart):

- https://mrcsabatoth.github.io/GoogleChartsTalk/22-diff-chart/
- https://github.com/MrCsabaToth/GoogleChartsTalk/blob/master/22-diff-chart/index.html

Comment: Do you have any reference for the available diff-options? Specifically, I'm having trouble configuring the "Previous data" legend of a Diff Chart.

Comment: I had trouble with that as well. I wish the whole shebang would be open source.